# error occur on HttpTransportSE call method in android

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

i am making one example of calling wsdl webservice made in Zend (framework of php) and i am using ksoap api(jar file) and i got this error

`org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions name='Ccc_Core_Model_Api_Server' targetNamespace='http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api'>@2:385 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40539078)`

i read all questions of stackoverflow related to this error, but i am not able to solve this error.

what is the real solution of this error ?

please help me.

my wsdl xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>              
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Ccc_Core_Model_Api_Server" targetNamespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"> 
<types>             
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>  
</types>    
<portType name="Ccc_Core_Model_Api_ServerPort">  
<operation name="addition">  
<documentation> This method is used for addition of two numbers</documentation>
<input message="tns:additionIn"/>
<output message="tns:additionOut"/>
</operation> 
<operation name="substraction">   
<documentation> This method is used for substraction of two numbers</documentation> 
<input message="tns:substractionIn"/>
<output message="tns:substractionOut"/>  
</operation>    
<operation name="multiple">  
<documentation>This method is used for multiple of two numbers</documentation>   
<input message="tns:multipleIn"/> 
<output message="tns:multipleOut"/>  
</operation> 
<operation name="division">   
<documentation>This method is used for division of two numbers</documentation>
<input message="tns:divisionIn"/> 
<output message="tns:divisionOut"/> 
</operation>   
</portType>  
<binding name="Ccc_Core_Model_Api_ServerBinding" type="tns:Ccc_Core_Model_Api_ServerPort">  
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="addition">  
<soap:operation soapAction="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api#addition"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/> 
</input> 
<output> 
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>  
</output>  
</operation>   
<operation name="substraction">  
<soap:operation soapAction="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api#substraction"/> 
<input>   
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>
</input>  
<output>   
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>  
</output>
</operation>  
<operation name="multiple"> 
<soap:operation soapAction="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api#multiple"/>  
<input>    
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>
</input>   
<output>  
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>
</output>
</operation>   
<operation name="division">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api#division"/>    
<input>  
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>   
</input>
<output>   
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/> 
</output>  
</operation>  
</binding>  
<service name="Ccc_Core_Model_Api_ServerService">  
<port name="Ccc_Core_Model_Api_ServerPort" binding="tns:Ccc_Core_Model_Api_ServerBinding">  
<soap:address location="http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"/>  
</port>  
</service>   
<message name="additionIn">   
<part name="param1" type="xsd:int"/>   
<part name="param2" type="xsd:int"/>  
</message> 
<message name="additionOut">  
<part name="return" type="xsd:float"/>  
</message>   
<message name="substractionIn"> 
<part name="param1" type="xsd:int"/> 
<part name="param2" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>    
<message name="substractionOut">   
<part name="return" type="xsd:float"/>     
</message>     
<message name="multipleIn">     
<part name="param1" type="xsd:int"/>      
<part name="param2" type="xsd:int"/>
</message> 
<message name="multipleOut">   
<part name="return" type="xsd:float"/>    
</message>   
<message name="divisionIn">    
<part name="param1" type="xsd:float"/>  
<part name="param2" type="xsd:float"/> 
</message>    
<message name="divisionOut"> 
<part name="return" type="xsd:float"/>  
</message>
</definitions>
```

exception stack trace:

```
06-14 15:45:49.527: D/AndroidRuntime(2055): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-14 15:45:49.527: D/AndroidRuntime(2055): CheckJNI is ON
06-14 15:45:50.587: D/AndroidRuntime(2055): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-14 15:45:50.637: D/AndroidRuntime(2055): Shutting down VM
06-14 15:45:50.657: D/dalvikvm(2055): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-14 15:45:50.657: I/AndroidRuntime(2055): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-14 15:45:50.669: D/jdwp(2055): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-14 15:45:50.677: D/dalvikvm(2055): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-14 15:45:51.247: D/AndroidRuntime(2065): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-14 15:45:51.247: D/AndroidRuntime(2065): CheckJNI is ON
06-14 15:45:52.147: D/AndroidRuntime(2065): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-14 15:45:52.197: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.phpwebservice/.PhpwebservicedemoActivity } from pid 2065
06-14 15:45:52.267: D/AndroidRuntime(2065): Shutting down VM
06-14 15:45:52.317: D/dalvikvm(2065): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+1ms
06-14 15:45:52.389: V/Adapter(1868): URL = http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api?wsdl
06-14 15:45:52.389: D/jdwp(2065): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-14 15:45:52.389: D/dalvikvm(2065): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-14 15:45:52.447: V/Adapter(1868): NAMESPACE = http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api
06-14 15:45:52.447: V/Adapter(1868): METHOD_NAME = addition
06-14 15:45:52.447: V/Adapter(1868): SOAP_ACTION = http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api#addition
06-14 15:45:52.447: V/Adapter(1868): request = addition{param1=10; param2=2; }
06-14 15:45:52.487: V/Adapter(1868): param1 = 10  param2 = 2
06-14 15:45:53.737: W/System.err(1868): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions name='Ccc_Core_Model_Api_Server' targetNamespace='http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api'>@2:385 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40541998) 
06-14 15:45:53.757: W/System.err(1868):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
06-14 15:45:53.757: W/System.err(1868):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:1424)
06-14 15:45:53.757: W/System.err(1868):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
06-14 15:45:53.766: W/System.err(1868):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
06-14 15:45:53.766: W/System.err(1868):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
06-14 15:45:53.766: W/System.err(1868):     at com.phpwebservice.Adapter.addition(Adapter.java:59)
06-14 15:45:53.777: W/System.err(1868):     at com.phpwebservice.PhpwebservicedemoActivity.onCreate(PhpwebservicedemoActivity.java:53)
06-14 15:45:53.777: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 15:45:53.787: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 15:45:53.787: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 15:45:53.787: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 15:45:53.787: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 15:45:53.809: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 15:45:53.809: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 15:45:53.809: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 15:45:53.809: W/System.err(1868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 15:45:53.817: W/System.err(1868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 15:45:53.817: W/System.err(1868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 15:45:53.817: W/System.err(1868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 15:45:53.817: W/System.err(1868):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 15:45:53.817: V/log_tag(1868): total addition = 0.0
06-14 15:45:54.069: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.phpwebservice/.PhpwebservicedemoActivity: +1s835ms
06-14 15:45:59.297: D/dalvikvm(126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 50% free 3003K/5895K, external 5903K/7371K, paused 63ms
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the xml, from what you posted I think there's no start tag. If you post more stack trace, it may be easier to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

wooo....

finally after 3 days try I got the solution,

the problem was in URL,

URL was **"http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api?wsdl"**

now i change it to ***"http://gsmadmin.com/zendtest/api"***

but i dont know why needs to remove ?wsdl from the url, because in previous project I used the URL with ?wsdl(which was made in java - JAX-WS-RI ) at last, but in recent if i use the URL with ?wsdl then it gives me error,

Both webservice are made in different technology, one in JAVA and another in zend(php framework) so may be structure is different,

but finally feel relax.....

thanks.......